# WebKit userContentController:didReceiveScriptMessage: not getting called for iOS 13

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, webkit, wkwebview

I am using `WKWebView` for showing web content into my app but I am not able to get a message sent from `JS` `webkit` on iOS 13 devices.
On previous iOS versions, it's working as expected.

**Setup:**

```
func setupWebView() {
    let config: WKWebViewConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    config.userContentController.add(self, name: "mobileApp")
    webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame, configuration: config)
    webView?.navigationDelegate = self
    webView?.uiDelegate = self
    webView?.scrollView.bounces = false
    webView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    self.view.addSubview(webView!)
    self.webView?.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: self.stringURL!)!))
}
```

**WKScriptMessageHandler Delegate:**

```
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, 
                                didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
    let data = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: message.body as! Dictionary)
    //Method is not getting called
}
```

**From JavaScript I am calling it like this :**

```
webkit.messageHandlers.mobileApp.postMessage({ 'backToApp': '1' });
```

Please let me know if anyone has come across this issue and some possible solution to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of searching, I found the solution that in iOS 13 `user agent` property is changed which we were used in `WEB` to check if it is mobile or not.
`isMobile` check was failing because of that our message handler was not getting called.

A lot of breaking changes have been done in iOS 13 that currently we need to take care.

Comment: How did you resolve the problem?